# Remind me to re-examine question with missing bits, if it does not get edited

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

A pattern I observe. Someone posts a question that lacks some critical information. They write coherently and supply a fair amount of detail -- it's not just 'plz send me the codez', and they don't seem to have fundamental telepathic expectations. None the less, not enough information to answer. So, it seems somewhat churlish to vote to close before giving them a bit of time to respond to comments requesting more information.

However, out of sight, out of mind. If they don't ever come back and improve the question, it just sits there being relatively useless, and serving as a mediocre example.

I wish I could leave some sort of flag that caused me to be pinged in, oh, a week, if there were no edits.

I offer one example of the species: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903059/java-ssl-connection-issue).

Comment: I star questions for that..

Comment: A good idea @MartijnPieters

Comment: @MartijnPieters That confuses the purpose of star and it means if you have quite a few stars of your own they'll get mixed up and lost in the shuffle.

Comment: @ArtB: It works for me. *shrug*. Note that I didn't say the OP should star questions for that purpose, or that you should. It means that I don't care much for this feature request, I *personally* do not see the need for it.

Comment: Hmm , IMHO, the question you linked us to *does* look a bit ill-prepared. When I read " write coherently and supply a fair amount of detail " I was thinking something bigger, with code...

Comment: Fair enough, perhaps it deserved to be not-a-real from birth.